# Crossfilter1.4.6 Filter likes not work when dimension with array, still can get the row with empty array after filter function

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

When I tested Part1 code, always get the row with the empty row after filter function.
Part1:

```
var rows = [{id: 1, links: ["vv"]}, {id: 2, links: []}];
var ndx = crossfilter(rows);
var dimLinks = ndx.dimension(r => r.links, true)
dimLinks.filter("vv");
console.log('links filter applied:', dimLinks.top(Infinity));//the result return [{id: 1, links: ["vv"]}, {id: 2, links: []}], not [{id: 1, links: ["vv"]}]
```

But when I tested Part2 code, l will not get the row with the empty row after filter function.
Part2:

```
var rows = [{id: 1, links: ["vv", "ss"]}, {id: 2, links: []}];
var ndx = crossfilter(rows);
var dimLinks = ndx.dimension(r => r.links, true)
dimLinks.filter("vv");
console.log('links filter applied:', dimLinks.top(Infinity));//the result return [{id: 1, links: ["vv", "ss"]}]
```

It looks like this caused by the row's array data. Is there incorrect call function when I used? And how And how can I filter the empty row under the case like the Part1? Thanks for help.

Comment: Pretty sure the first result is a bug. As [documented](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays), if the dimension function returns an empty array for a row, that row will not be counted in any group. The row clearly doesn't match this filter, either! [More discussion in this issue](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/pull/129).

Comment: I filed an [issue on GitHub with some more failing test cases](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/141). Until it gets resolved, I guess you'd just have to filter out these invalid results with `.top(Infinity).filter(r => r.links.length)` as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your help.l will use your scheme for the moment and improve after the issue fixed.Thanks.